# Does Kafka have a visibility timeout?

Tags: apache-kafka

Does Kafka have something analogues to an SQS visibility timeout?

What is the property called?
I can't seem to find anything like this in the [docs](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html).

Answer (score 4):

Kafka works a little bit differently than SQS.

Every message resides on a single topic partition. Kafka consumers are organized into consumer groups. A single partition can be assigned only to a single consumer in a group. That means that other consumers from the same CG won't get the same message and the same message will only be re-sent if the same consumer pulls messages from a broker and hasn't committed the offset.

If Kafka broker designated as group coordinator detects that consumer died, rebalance happens and that partition can be assigned to another consumer. But again this will be the only consumer that gets messages from that partition.

So as you can see since Kafka is not using the competing consumer pattern,  there's no notion of `visibility timeout`.

Comment: what does it mean `hasn't committed the offset` ? There is a timeout of some sort for that right? Does kafka wait some time before assuming that the consumer has not committed?

Comment: no, if Kafka consumer doesn't commit the offset and fetch messages, it will get the same messages (starting from last committed offset)